# bootclasspath in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, classloader, bootclasspath

I'm trying to provide a slightly different implementation of `java.util.Date` (for experimental purposes) .  I rewrote it, packaged my `java.util.Date` in a `jar` and used `-Xbootclasspath/p:fullpathto.jar` as a VM parameter.  When running a standalone, it picks it up and works nicely.  However, when I try to set this **bootclasspath** argument in `Tomcat` (using WTP eclipse) it doesn't use my modified `java.util.Date.`

I configured it in VM arguments under Launch configuration.

Anybody has an idea of why this could be?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you try to take a look at the command arguments that are being used when Eclipse (?) launches the JVM to run Tomcat.  On Linux, I'd use `ps -efl | grep java` to find this out ...

For reference: this Eclipse [forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/65568/) gives 2 ways to set the bootclasspath in an Eclipse Launcher:

- You can add a -Xbootclasspath option to the JVM args.
- You can change the bootclasspath in the classpath tab.

Comment: hi stephen, i tried that already by using procexp to verify that the arguments are correctly passed.  it's not that the argument is not passed, it's just that nothing is done with it...

Comment: actually, adding the jar to the Bootstrap Entries under classpath does the trick!  -Xbootclasspath seems to be ignored or overridden!

Answer (score 0):

Check an answer for this question:

[Overriding application server behaviour for loading jsp-api and servlet-api jars in a packaged web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325171/overriding-application-server-behaviour-for-loading-jsp-api-and-servlet-api-jars)

You might be using wrong path format. Make sure you use quotation if your path contains spacing.